# How to convert authorid into postid so that i can extract author details and store in my authorDocument array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

**Why this code isn't working? **

```
let posts = await postsCollection.aggregate([
  {$match: {_id: new ObjectID(id)}},
  {$addFields: {authorId: { $toObjectId: "$author"}}},
  {$lookup: {from: "users", localField: "author", foreignField: "_id", as: "authorDocument"}}
]).toArray()
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Below should work.. I presume that postsCollection and users are the collection you want to join based on authorId as common key but its stored as string in postsCollection  and as _id in users.

```
let posts = await postsCollection.aggregate([
  {$match: {_id: new ObjectID(id)}},
  {$addFields: {authorId: { $toObjectId: "$author"}}},
  {$lookup: {from: "users", localField: "authorId", foreignField: "_id", as: "authorDocument"}}
]).toArray()
```

Note: you have used author but it should be authorId

Comment: nope, didn't work, mate.

Comment: can you share sample document from both collection?

Comment: what do you mean by both collection ?

Comment: post collection and user collection  for example here i have sample data of two collections and lookup : https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZuGX9-2bNKg

Comment: const postsCollection = require('../db').db().collection("posts");

Comment: i mean to ask sample document from both collection. So by looking at a sample record we can fix the aggregate query if anything is missing.

Comment: i have store the posts in variable postscollection i.e. const postsCollection = require('../db').db().collection("posts"); and users will lookup in users Atlast in MongoDB database.

Comment: for lookup to work you need to ensure that you correctly map local field and foreign field. Based on sample i think you have document id for posts. and then you add field authorId(ObjectId) by converting author from post, and doing lookup based on _id from users. So if you can check in compass that for given author is there a matching _id found in users?

Comment: if you use mongo compass then you can test this quickly in aggregation tab of mongo compass.

Comment: yup, when we manually copy and paste the userid, it's matching and extracting all the details of user from db contrast to do itself automatically?